# What's a galaxy question?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I'm watching [a MSNBC commentary about Syria war and @6:02](https://youtu.be/_O2TRzA2ezk?t=363) where a guest says:

> That's a galaxy question

What's the meaning of galaxy question? Does it mean the question is off-topic? Or it mean it's a big problem that is hard to be answered?

**Note**: The video contains opinions about the conflict in Syria. I am only interested in the English. Please do not click the link if you don't want to hear about the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He doesn't say "That's a galaxy question". He says "That's [Galaxy Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Quest)" in response to the interviewer's question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I shouldn't trust auto generated translation...

Comment: Wow so it seems like the guest is interrupted by the name "Tim Allen?" by the host in the video?

Comment: That's right.  The interviewer may not have seen *Starship Troopers*, or is unsure about the title, and so asks, “Is that the one with Tim Allen?” “No, that's *Galaxy Quest* I think.”  (Yes, Tim Allen was in *Galaxy Quest*.)